# How to trigger Laravel SQLSTATE error on localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I keep getting the following error whenever I deploy my Laravel application remotely, but locally the same code runs fine.

The error is:
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'cronut.events.date' isn't in GROUP BY`

The query can be manually run on the remote server, so this is a syntax check that's performed by Laravel (or at least before it reaches the database server).

So how can I trigger this same syntax checking and get the same SQLSTATE error on localhost? I cannot see anything that suggests Laravel shouldn't throw this error on localhost?

Comment: Are the local and remote versions of MySQL the same? I know this changed at some point so that could be it?

Comment: @GiovanniS As I say, the above query runs when executed manually on the remote server. This is apparently an error before it gets there.

Comment: I doubt that laravel would do a syntax check on the sql query. This error message comes from mysql.

Comment: @Shadow As I say, the query returned with SQLSTATE runs when executed manually on the remote server with no problems. My remote MySQL server is running 5.6 -- so ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY isn't even on.

Comment: You can set sql mode on session level, that's a more likely explanation.

Comment: @Shadow And where is SQL Mode being turned on then?